# Better way to sending HTML from Endpoint in Astro

Tags: html, htmx, astrojs

I read in the [documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/endpoints/#server-endpoints-api-routes) about how to use Endpoints to send `json`, to send images, for redirects, for form validation, but I want to send `html`.

I want to use `Astro` together with `htmx` and am trying to use server to send small snippets of `html`. Here's what I got:

Tha backend part:

```
// clicked.ts file

import type { APIContext } from 'astro';

export async function post({ cookies, params, request }: APIContext) {
  return new Response(
    `<button hx-post="/clicked" hx-swap="outerHTML">
      Click me again
     </button>`,
    { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' } }
  );
}
```

and the frontend part:

```
  <button hx-post="/clicked" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    Click Me
  </button>
```

But I don't like the ugly look of sending `html` as a string, would like to reuse `Astro` templates.

Answer (score 1):

Using Astro's server-side rendering capabilities, we can implement this desired functionality without the need to create an additional endpoint. We can use the front-matter of an `.astro` page to accomplish this.

First, make sure your `astro.config.mjs` includes `output: "hybrid"`, like so:

```
// astro.config.mjs
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

export default defineConfig({
  output: "hybrid",
});
```

Then, create the `src/pages/clicked.astro` file:

```
---
// src/pages/clicked.astro

export const partial = true
export const prerender = false
---
<button hx-post="/clicked" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    Click me again
</button>
```

**Your initial "Click Me" button should now work!**

Moreover, here's a better example of a comprehensive implementation for a server-side rendered partial page, directly from within an `.astro` file - ready to use with HTMX.

```
--
// src/pages/chat/gpt_response.astro

import ChatMessage from "../../components/chat/ChatMessage.astro"
import OpenAI from "openai"

export const partial = true
export const prerender = false

const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: import.meta.env.OPENAI_API_KEY })

// Get user input from query string (hx-vars)
let userInput = Astro.url.searchParams.get('user_input') || 'Hello, AI!';

// Prepare the chat messages
let messages = [
    { role: "system", content: "Your system message here." },
    { role: "assistant", content: "Hey there! I'm ready to chat." },
    { role: "user", content: userInput }
];

// Create chat completion with OpenAI
const gptChatResponse = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: messages,
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    max_tokens: 125,
})

// Extract response
let gptResponse = gptChatResponse.choices[0].message.content

---
<ChatMessage sender='gpt' text={gptResponse}/>
```

It creates a chat completion using OpenAI's API, and then includes the generated response directly inside an Astro component's props.

*Note: The code in the front-matter runs within the server each time you make a request, prior to rendering the component. The response itself only includes the HTML of the rendered component.*

This page can now be rendered using HTMX, like so:

```
<button hx-get="/chat/gpt_response" 
        hx-vars="{'user_input':'HTMX with Astro is pretty neat.'}" 
        hx-target="#chat-container" 
        hx-swap="beforeend">
    Click Me
</button>
```

[By the way, they recently added official support for "partial" pages.](https://astro.build/blog/astro-340/) However, I don't know what difference it makes to set the `export const partial = true` inside your .astro file yet.